# Creating a one-to-one relation for a pre-existing record using Doctrine ORM (1.2)

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, relationship, one-to-one

**Background / Application**

I have two database tables, `supplier` and `address` with a one-to-one relationship, as not all suppliers have an address (and this is just a simplified example from a larger application). I'm using the Doctrine ORM (1.2) with a MySQL database.

I am having troubles with adding an address to a pre-existing supplier who doesn't have one. I can modify the address of a pre-existing supplier who does have one without issue.

The following schema and four simple scripts display what is happening at each stage of the process.

**Schema**

```
Address:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    town: string(300)

Supplier:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name: string(300)
    address_id: integer
  relations:
    Address:
      foreignType: one
```

**Script One: Create two suppliers, with and without an address**

```
$supplier = new Supplier();
$supplier->name = 'A supplier with an address';
$supplier->Address->town = 'A town';
$supplier->save();

$supplier = new Supplier();
$supplier->name = 'A supplier without an address';
$supplier->save();
```

**Script Two: Confirm data has been saved**

```
$supplier = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Supplier')->find(1);
var_dump($supplier->toArray());

$supplier = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Supplier')->find(2);
var_dump($supplier->toArray());
```

Output:

```
array
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'A supplier with an address' (length=26)
  'address_id' => string '1' (length=1)
array
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'A supplier without an address' (length=29)
  'address_id' => null
```

**Script Three: Fetch and update / create an address**

```
$supplier = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Supplier')->find(1);
$supplier->Address->town = 'A Different Town';
$supplier->save();
var_dump($supplier->toArray());

$supplier = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Supplier')->find(2);
$supplier->Address->town = 'A New Town';
$supplier->save();
var_dump($supplier->toArray());
```

Output: *(Note, at this point, it would suggest that the address was created for the second supplier who previously didn't have an address)*

```
array
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'A supplier with an address' (length=26)
  'address_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'Address' => 
    array
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'town' => string 'A Different Town' (length=16)
array
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'A supplier without an address' (length=29)
  'address_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'Address' => 
    array
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'town' => string 'A New Town' (length=10)
```

**Script Four: Confirm that the changes were saved**

```
$supplier = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Supplier')->find(1);
var_dump($supplier->toArray());

$supplier = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Supplier')->find(2);
var_dump($supplier->toArray());

$address = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Address')->find(2);
var_dump($address->toArray());
```

Output:

```
array
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'A supplier with an address' (length=26)
  'address_id' => string '1' (length=1)
array
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'A supplier without an address' (length=29)
  'address_id' => null
array
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'town' => string 'A New Town' (length=10)
```

Can anyone explain why the address for the second supplier is being inserted into the database but not actually being linked to the supplier?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Doctrine. I Use Propel, but I think that if you save the supplier you are not saving the address in database.

You need to save the changes in address before you save the supplier.

In pseudocode:

```
 $supplier=Supplier::find(2);

 $supplier->address->name="New town";

 $supplier->adress->save(); //saving de change in database. If you don't do it your change is only in the object
```

An alternative:

```
 $supplier=Supplier::find(2);

 $address= new Adress();
 $adress->name="New town";
 $adress->save();

 $supplier->adress=$adress;
 $supplier->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Curlas. The first suggestion to run the save method on the address relationship doesn't appear to work as you expected with Doctrine. It has a similar output to my Script Three above; the supplier object has the Address property, but this time the address_id property is null.

The second suggestion is similar to what I'm using at the moment as a work-around to my problem. I'm checking for the existence of the relation with `$supplier->relatedExists('Address')` and either changing the pre-existing address, or creating a new address.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I like to do when working with doctrine objects, especially in an iteration, and if it is giving me problems is to unset the object before creating a new one. Try unsetting

```
unset($supplier)
```

the first object before assigning the $supplier a new doctrine object.